# Google Sheets, Is it possible to use Arrayformula to expand formulas downward when the formula uses arrays

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I've been using Arrayformula to auto-expand formulas (such as "=Left(A2:A,B2:B-1") downward, but I need some help understanding this formula. I've read up on the function itself and browsed many forums about this but I can only find articles explaining how to use this with simple formulas, so I'm going to try to as this as simply as possible here: Is it possible to use Arrayformula to expand formulas downward when the formula uses arrays?

The summary for Arrayformula reads "Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of **non-array** functions with arrays." This was my understanding of how Arrayformula populated a formula into rows automatically. Using this I thought of it as writing a formula that generated an array of formulas, and then splitting them up with Arrayformula. This seems to not work with some formulas such as concatenate, which I will focus my question on. This example is far from my real life problem, but if someone could show me a solution I can apply it elsewhere.

[Arrayformula spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9s2f.jpg)

Usually when I use Arrayformula with A1:A it would expand the formula through the column, referencing the corresponding rows as it went. With this example I  want to have Column C be the concatenated result of columns A and B. Is this possible with Arrayformula? This question is not specific to concatenate, that is just the simplest one that came to mind. Another example would be Countif. Lets say I want to see how many values in the first 5 columns are over 20, and I want that formula to auto populate down, is that possible and if so how would it be done?

[Arrayformula second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHMoP.jpg)

P.S. Please don't say copy the formula using the drag handle in the lower right.

Comment: No that's not what I want. I think I simplified the question too much because that definitely is a solution to what I asked, and thank you, but I'm trying to understand the specifics of why some formulas work inside arrayformula and others don't. I'll edit my post a bit to reflect that.

Comment: That's what I expected sadly. So there is no way to have Arrayformula copy down formulas that use those functions such as concatenate?

Comment: Ok good to know. I'll focus more on finding alternative functions, thank you.

Comment: @Jefferson I don't know why these comments have been deleted, I'm looking for something similar to you, and without context I don't understand your comments.